# jackson not generating expected json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using fasterxml jackson apis to generate below json string:

```
"head" : { label : "head", data : [[2001,5678],[2002,6127]] }
```

However, below string is generated without comma and extra colons and curly braces:

```
{"head":{"label":"head","data":{:[{:2001:5678}]:[{:2002:6127}]}}}
```

code:

```
JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createGenerator(writer);

jGenerator.writeStartObject();

jGenerator.writeObjectFieldStart("head");
jGenerator.writeStringField("label", "head");

jGenerator.writeObjectFieldStart("data");

jGenerator.writeStartArray();
jGenerator.writeStartObject();

jGenerator.writeNumber(2001);
jGenerator.writeNumber(5678);

jGenerator.writeEndObject();
jGenerator.writeEndArray();

jGenerator.writeStartArray();
jGenerator.writeStartObject();

jGenerator.writeNumber(2002);
jGenerator.writeNumber(6127);

jGenerator.writeEndObject();
jGenerator.writeEndArray();

jGenerator.writeEndObject();
jGenerator.writeEndObject();

jGenerator.close();

LOGGER.info(writer.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JsonGenerator` is a tool for writing the pieces of a JSON value. It will write whatever you tell it to write in the appropriate context.

```
jGenerator.writeStartObject(); // {

jGenerator.writeObjectFieldStart("head"); // {"head": {
jGenerator.writeStringField("label", "head"); // {"head": {"label":"head"

jGenerator.writeObjectFieldStart("data"); // {"head": {"label":"head", "data": {

// you're in the context of an object, so a name is expected, it will be empty when written
jGenerator.writeStartArray(); // {"head": {"label":"head", "data": {:[
jGenerator.writeStartObject(); // {"head": {"label":"head", "data": {:[{
// again, you're in the context of an object, so a name is expected
jGenerator.writeNumber(2001); // {"head": {"label":"head", "data": {:[{:2001
```

Given your expected results, this

```
jGenerator.writeObjectFieldStart("data"); // {"head": {"label":"head", "data": {
```

should actually be an array field start

```
jGenerator.writeArrayFieldStart("data"); // {"head": {"label":"head", "data": [
```

And you then shouldn't be writing start of objects, just arrays.